# Does being a "Yeoman" imply that the person is a "Bachelor"

Tags: church-records, occupation

I have seen in english church marriage registers:
`Richard Carver of this parish, yeoman`
and `Elizabeth Chapman of this parish, spinster`
and was wondering if a yeoman must be unmarried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I have a number of direct ancestors who were yeomen and married.  I think of them as having been small landholding farmers.

For a definition of a yeoman see, for example, https://www.britannica.com/topic/yeoman:

> **yeoman**, in English history, a class intermediate between the gentry and the labourers; a yeoman was usually a landholder but could
> also be a retainer, guard, attendant, or subordinate official.

As [commented by @AdrianB38](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/does-being-a-yeoman-imply-that-the-person-is-a-bachelor/18939?noredirect=1#comment28331_18939):

> Qualifiers in marriage entries (eg bachelor or labourer) can be quite
> inconsistent. While the full version is usually marital status and
> occupation, either or even both may be omitted in my experience. As
> here, it is not unknown to get marital status for one party and
> occupation for the other.

[by @jadepx](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/does-being-a-yeoman-imply-that-the-person-is-a-bachelor/18939?noredirect=1#comment28333_18939):

> the status/occupation just indicates what the author of the entry knew
> of the marriage (or more precisely, what they remembered/recollected
> when actually writing down the entry.

and [by @JanMurphy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/does-being-a-yeoman-imply-that-the-person-is-a-bachelor/18939?noredirect=1#comment28345_18939):

> There's an extensive article about the history and uses of the word
> yeoman in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeoman but it
> doesn't address the marital status of the person.  It would be easier
> to use references to answer the question if we knew the date of the
> parish register in question, but we can assume a 'ballpark figure' of
> 1600 or following.